# if else conditions not checking properly in c#?

Tags: c#

I am coming to a problem where I am checking if some of the elements key values are valid in order to proceed with the QR code scanning. For example: If my Active attribute is true, and completed is false and the schedule time is current time +- 30 minutes of start window then proceed with the scanning. If not, let me show them an error. I tried implementing the checking part with a simple if - but only checking the active, and completed key values. Can anyone check and help me solve this issue. thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
     public void ScanQrCode()
     {

         BarcodeScanner.Scan(async (barCodeType, barCodeValue) =>
         {
             BarcodeScanner.Stop();


             var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(barCodeValue);
             var gettingTheName = (string) results.Evaluation.Value;
             TextHeader.text = gettingTheName;
             var qrCodeString = $"***************.firebaseio.com/Evaluations/.json?orderBy=\"$key\"&startAt=\"{gettingTheName}\"&limitToFirst=1";
             Debug.Log(barCodeValue);

                           var qrCodeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(qrCodeString);


                       try
              {

                   bool parseSuccessful = DateTime.TryParse("ScheduleStartTime", out var scheduledStartTime);
                  if (results.Contains("Active").Equals(true) &&
                      results.Contains("Completed").Equals(false) &&
                      DateTime.Now < scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes(30) &&
                      DateTime.Now > scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes(-30)) {

                      var matchingLink = new WebClient().DownloadString(qrCodeString);
                      var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(matchingLink);
                      var candidateId = obj.First.First["CandiateID"].ToString();
                      string page = $"https://***********.firebaseio.com/Candidates/.json?orderBy=\"$key\"&startAt=\"{candidateId}\"&limitToFirst=1";

                      using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                      using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
                      using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                      {
                          // Reading the string. 
                          Dictionary<string, Candidates> evaluationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Candidates>();
                          string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                          evaluationDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Candidates>>(result);
                          Debug.Log(evaluationDictionary);

                          foreach (Candidates candidates in evaluationDictionary.Values)
                          {
                              string evaluationMessage = candidates.FirstName + " " + candidates.LastName;
                              candidateMessage = GetComponent<Text>();
                              candidateMessage.text = evaluationMessage;

                          }


                          // Getting a reference to the text component.
                          candidateMessage = GetComponent<Text>();
                          candidateMessage.text = matchingLink.ToString();
                          candidateMessage.text = matchingLink.Trim(new char[] {'"'});

                      }

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Incorrect credentials", "Please scan a valid QR code", "OK");
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(e);
                  SceneManager.LoadScene("Verify");
                  throw;
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

JSON:

```
    {
    "Active": true,
    "Completed": false,
    "ScheduleStartTime": "2019-12-16T20:10:57.649418-08:00"
}
```

Comment: I don't see any validation on schedule time.

Comment: Yeah. I was kind of stuck on that part too. I tried doing it by adding `&& qrCodeString.Contains("ScheduleStartTime").Equals(*I GOT STUCK IN HERE*)`

Comment: Also, is the validation for my rest of my fields good enough?  However, when lets says if the Active is false and completed is true I dont want to  take them to the Verify scene

Comment: @Crowcoder I updated my code. Now, It only fires the `else cause` instead even if the key values are met.

Comment: Please refrain from [duplicating your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493311/if-else-statement-fires-only-else-condition-in-c?noredirect=1#comment105160886_59493311)

Comment: This is the first question I posted @Amy I deleted that one because I already have it here. I am updating my question as we speak.

Comment: I know this is the first one you posted, I can see the timestamps.  In the future, please don't duplicate your questions.

Comment: @Amy I have updated my code.  The code right now it just not checks for the fields of `if (results.Contains("Active").Equals(true) &&
                      results.Contains("Completed").Equals(false) &&
                      DateTime.Now < scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes(30) &&
                      DateTime.Now > scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes(-30))` it just lets the user bypass after scanning.

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah. I was kind of stuck on that part too. I tried doing it by adding
>   && qrCodeString.Contains("ScheduleStartTime").Equals(*I GOT STUCK IN
>   HERE*)

I'd accomplish this portion by parsing the date string to a DateTime object, then comparing the current time with your new DateTime shifted in both directions.

I might do something like this:

```
try {
                bool parseSuccessful = DateTime.TryParse( ScheduledStartTimeFromJSON, out var scheduledStartTime );
                if ( qrCodeString.Contains( "Active" ).Equals( true ) &&
                     qrCodeString.Contains( "CompletedMessage" ).Equals( false ) &&
                     DateTime.Now < scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes(30) && 
                     DateTime.Now > scheduledStartTime.AddMinutes( -30 ) ) {
                    var matchingLink = new WebClient().DownloadString( qrCodeString );
                    ...
                }
            }
```

You should also check to make sure the date was parsed successfully before comparing it to anything.

Comment: also, is my else if validation correct and my catch clause as well?

Comment: I did this at  first `bool parseSuccessful = DateTime.TryParse("ScheduleStartTime", out var scheduledStartTime );`  However, I get my QR code scanned but it wont fire the else if or catch cause?

Comment: ScheduledStartTimeFromJSON should be what ever variable or function you use to access the date string. Your validation otherwise looks correct. In your catch block, I would recommend writing e.StackTrace to console or adding a break point anywhere in the block to help you debug. I don't know what SceneManager is and I assume the reason you are re-throwing is because you have some other higher-level error handling.

Comment: SceneManager is where I load the next scene.  Also, how to make the higher-level error handling working properly? If in the database, I change the active to false, and completed to true I want to show my else cause.

Comment: You should set a break point before the if statement and examine the variables you are comparing to verify they are what you expect. A catch block is only executed if an error occurs in its respective try block. There are hundreds of tutorials to handle exceptions in an application. TutorialsPoint is an OK place to start. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm

Comment: right, I put a breakpoint on line `bool parseSuccessful = ....`  and step over. But yet, the when those variables are not valid, the `EditorUtility.DisplayDialog` does not display.

Comment: is it okay if `parseSuccessful` is unused?

Comment: Also, I was mistaken regarding your validation. qrCodeString.Contains( "Active" ).Equals( true ) will always return true and qrCodeString.Contains( "CompletedMessage" ).Equals( false ) will always return false because the value of the entire string is being checked, not the value of just the JSON key:value pair. If an exception is thrown in the if statement, the else will not be executed, execution moves straight to the catch block. It is fine for parseSuccessful to be unused, I included it merely to show it was available for error handling.

Comment: I also updated my code without the `try-catch` block. Still it does not make the code work? The QR code is scanning works, but does not do the code inside the if cause and even in the else if.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON example:

- First i think you should check for **Completed** value insted of **CompletedMessage**.
- Secound with this code `qrCodeString.Contains("Active").Equals(true)` you are just checking if **Active** is contained in the string. I think you should be looking for the value of it.

In my vision the right way to do the check you need is to first deserialize the JSON like this

```
var qrCodeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(qrCodeString);
```

And then check for the respectives values

```
if (qrCodeObj["Active"] == true && qrCodeObj["Completed"] == false)
{
   var matchingLink = new WebClient().DownloadString(qrCodeString);
   var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject (matchingLink);
   var candidateId = obj.First.First["CandiateID"].ToString();
   string page = $"https://*********.firebaseio.com/Candidates/.json?orderBy=\"$key\"&startAt=\"{candidateId}\"&limitToFirst=1";

   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
   using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
   using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
   {
     // Reading the string. 
     Dictionary<string, Candidates> evaluationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Candidates>();
     string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     evaluationDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Candidates>>(result);
     Debug.Log(evaluationDictionary);

     foreach (Candidates candidates in evaluationDictionary.Values)
       {
        string evaluationMessage = candidates.FirstName + " " + candidates.LastName;
        candidateMessage = GetComponent<Text>();
        candidateMessage.text = evaluationMessage;

       }


       // Getting a reference to the text component.
       candidateMessage = GetComponent<Text>();
       candidateMessage.text = matchingLink.ToString();
       candidateMessage.text = matchingLink.Trim(new char[] {'"'});


     }
}
else
{
   EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Incorrect Credentials ",
                 "Please scan a valid QR code. " , "OK");
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204907/discussion-on-answer-by-diogo-magro-if-else-conditions-not-checking-properly-in).